# How to make a message box appear after pressing a key

Tags: vb6

I'm currently playing around in Visual Basic 6.0 and wondered how can you cause a message box or some other code to appear/activate when the user presses a specific key on the keyboard like <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Where does user press the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Form_KeyDown(Keycode, Shift) method in your form:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyF1 Then
        //do something here if F1 key is pressed
        //or call a method


    End If
End Sub
```

Also, you might also want to set the KeyPreview property to true for your form.